# Calendar between two others with java.Calendar

Tags: java

I have to made a method that counts how many visitors attended between two dates.
Here is how i set the values for the visitors:

```
    System.out.println("Ingrese dia de la visita: ");
    fechaVisita.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese mes de la visita: ");
    fechaVisita.set(Calendar.MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese año de la visita: ");
    fechaVisita.set(Calendar.YEAR, txt.nextInt());
```

Here how i set the start date and the end date for the search:

```
    System.out.println("Ingrese dia desde: ");
    fechaDesde.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese mes desde: ");
    fechaDesde.set(Calendar.MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese año desde: ");
    fechaDesde.set(Calendar.YEAR, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese dia hasta: ");
    fechaHasta.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese mes hasta: ");
    fechaHasta.set(Calendar.MONTH, txt.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Ingrese año hasta: ");
    fechaHasta.set(Calendar.YEAR, txt.nextInt());
```

Then, i call the proper method "recaudacion":

```
    public int recaudacion(Calendar p_fechaDesde, Calendar p_fechaHasta)
    { 
        int cont = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.getVisitantes().size(); i++)
        {
           if(p_fechaDesde.after(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) && p_fechaHasta.before(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()))
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }
    return cont;
    }
```

But that does not work, the condition is never true, i don´t know why even if i put false values still false.
I aslo tried this:

```
    public int recaudacion(Calendar p_fechaDesde, Calendar p_fechaHasta)
    { 
        int cont = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<this.getVisitantes().size(); i++)
        {
           if(p_fechaDesde.compareTo(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) > 0 &&
           p_fechaHasta.compareTo(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) < 0)
            {
                cont++;
            }
        }
    return cont;
    }
```

But also does not work.
I don´t know what i´m missing, in theory that have to works, but no...

Comment: `return cont;` inside the loop. please learn proper formatting of the code, this avoids such obvious mistakes

Comment: Sorry, that was just an error to write the question.

Comment: ok. As far as I can see (and understand the variables correctly, it's not in English unfortunately), the condition seems to be correct - for each visitor, you're checking whether its visiting data is in between a given time range. Just to clarify, the visitors collection isn't empty? Did you double check the created dates? I mean, print for each visitor the date in the loop and check whether it's really between the given start and end date

Comment: Yes, i actually did that, i didn´t write it in the question so as not to confuse, The ArrayList of visitors(Visitante) isn't empy and have the dates i put in

Comment: I'm pretty sure that something is wrong with your dates. Can please post one example visitor that fails + start and end date given in the method then?

Comment: wait, desde is start, right? you have to use it in the other direction, i.e. `p_fechaDesde.after` is checking whether start date is after the date of the visitor. Use `before` here instead

Comment: `if(p_fechaDesde.before(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) && p_fechaHasta.after(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()))
           `

Comment: I was making the code in english so that everyone can understand, but i just tried what you said and it works.

Comment: So, i was doing it in the wrong way. Thanks AKSW

Comment: you should probably provide the solution as an answer and "accept" it such that others can see it has been solved. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was ussing before and after in the opposite way. 
Here´s the solution:

```
public int recaudacion(Calendar p_fechaDesde, Calendar p_fechaHasta)
{ 
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<this.getVisitantes().size(); i++)
    {
       if(p_fechaDesde.before(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) && p_fechaHasta.after(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()))
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }
return cont;
}
```

`

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Indenting your code properly would have shown that you `return` before the for loop ends

Change your function to

```
public int recaudacion(Calendar p_fechaDesde, Calendar p_fechaHasta) { 
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i=0 ; i < this.getVisitantes().size(); i++)
    {
        if(p_fechaDesde.after(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()) 
                && p_fechaHasta.before(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita()))
                    cont++;
    }
    return cont;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but this will definitely change the behavior of your `for` loop and maybe do something you want.

Comment: Sorry, that was just an error to write the question. I'm trying to count how many visitors came betwen two dates

Comment: No, that was an error when writing the question, not in the real code

Answer (score 0):

Convert Date in Numbers and compare numbers

```
 Long value1 = fechaVisita.getTimeInMillis();
 Long value2 = fechaDesde.getTimeInMillis();

 Long visitante = Calendar.getTimeInMillis();

 value1 < visitante < value2
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess add method getTime():

```
 if(p_fechaDesde.getTime().after(((Visitante)this.getVisitantes().get(i))
     .getFechaVisita().getTime()) &&   
 p_fechaHasta.getTime().before(((Visitante)this
     .getVisitantes().get(i)).getFechaVisita().getTime))
```